# How to share a variable with many "it" examples in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am using let to create a user record using factory girl. However i want to use exactly the same variable across 2 tests in the context as the user_id and email are important to the external API i am sending.

However i had no luck making a single variable for using across the examples. Here is my current code

```
context "User" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    it "should create user and return 'nil'" do
      expect(send_preferences(user, "new")).to eq nil
    end

    it "should not create user preferences again after sending two consecutive same requests" do
      expect(send_preferences(user, "new")).to eq "User preferences already saved. No need to re-save them."
    end

    it "should update user preferences" do
      expect(send_preferences(user, "update")).to eq nil
    end
  end
```

any clues?

Comment: Create a `before` block and assign an instance variable with `@variable_name` inside `context`. That should be available.

Comment: exactly the same _variable_ or exactly the same ___object___?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev same variable, ID and email to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lets within lets:

```
context "User" do
  let(:email_address) { 'test@test.com' }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email_address: email_address) }
```

You will then also have access to the email_address variable within all your tests.

This works because previously the email address was being randomly generated by the factory every time the user was created, as we hadn't set a value for it anywhere. So, we called the code below in each test:

```
send_preferences(user, "new")
```

It called the 'user' let which created a new user with a completely random email address (as we hadn't give it a specific email value). Therefore during the backend API call it was sending a different email address every time.

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

However, when we defined the email address 'let' as 'test@test.com', and passed that into the user factory as in the code I provided, we overrode the randomly generated email address with our own static value, So, every time we call the code again:

```
send_preferences(user, "new")
```

It now triggers the user factory create which is also taking our new 'email_address' let, which is always set to a specific value of test@test.com every time it is called.

```
let(:email_address) { 'test@test.com' }
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email_address: email_address) }
```

Therefore, when the backend API call is made the email address is always what we set it to.

Also, as it is a let we can use that variable in any of the tests themselves if we wish. For example:

```
it 'should set the email address' do
  expect(user.email_address).to eq(email_address)
end
```

It's quite hard to explain in a few sentences but let me know if that's still not clear.

Comment: this worked finally! However can you explain a bit more what happens here? i just put these two lines, nothing else changed in my tests. So find it a bit weird. Some more explanation would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Having an instantiated variable shared among multiple tests is an anti-pattern 90% of the time in my opinion.

The problem with doing something like the below is you will be creating objects in your db without doing a cleanup.

```
before(:all) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
end
```

Sure, you can do a `before(:after)` block or use DatabaseCleaner, but I think it is much better practice for tests to be as standalone as possible.  In your case, make your setup of a `send_preferences` event before making an expectation on what happens the second time:

```
context "User" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    # ...

    it "should not create user preferences again after sending two consecutive same requests" do
      send_preferences(user, "new") # Setup
      expect(send_preferences(user, "new")).to eq "User preferences already saved. No need to re-save them."
    end

    it "should update user preferences" do
      send_preferences(user, "new") # Setup
      expect(send_preferences(user, "update")).to eq nil
    end
  end
```